# Swashbuckle/Swagger - I need to remove incorrect parameters

Tags: c#, filter, swagger, swashbuckle

I have a number of Get operations in my Api. Currently the swagger document includes the following parameters:

```
"parameters": [
 {
    "in": "body",
    "name": "body",
    "schema": { }
 }
],
```

Is there any way to remove these using an OperationFilter? I've tried the following but the operations do not have any parameters

```
public class RemoveBodyParametersFilter : IOpenApiOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        var parametersToRemove = operation.Parameters.Where(p => p.Name == "body").ToList();
        foreach (var parameter in parametersToRemove)
        {
            operation.Parameters.Remove(parameter);
        }
    }
}
```

The endpoint looks like this:

```
[HttpGet(Name = "GetOperationStatus")]
[SwaggerConsumes("application/json")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(DtoBaseMgmtResponse), 200)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(DtoBaseMgmtResponse), 202)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(DtoBaseMgmtResponse), 400)]
[Metadata("Get an Operation Status", "Get the operation status for the operation ID provided.", VisibilityType.Internal)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetOperationStatus(string operationId)
```

Comment: That's being generated based on your method signature, so if you correct that, you don't have to use a filter to fix it. Please post the methods' signatures.

Comment: Remove `[SwaggerConsumes("application/json")]` from all GET operations. If you don't accept a request body, that attribute makes absolutely no sense.

Comment: We had our api rejected by Microsoft when we tried that & had to manually put the consumes back.

Comment: They could only have meant to put it on those methods that actually accept a request body. GET *can* accept a request body, and both ASP.NET Core and HttpClient support it, but since browsers will refuse to send the request, it's widely avoided.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I guess I'll have to go back to microsoft for clarification.